# Undefined references with ATLAS

Tags: gcc, linker, atlas

I was trying to use ATLAS in my project but I am unable to link even the simplest code with it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cblas.h>

void ATL_buildinfo(void);

int main() {
    ATL_buildinfo();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with:

```
gcc -I/home/caian/ATLAS/include/ \
  -I/home/caian/ATLAS/ARCH/include/ \
  -L/home/caian/ATLAS/ARCH/lib/ \
  -latlas main.c -o test
```

I double-checked the ATL_buildinfo prototype and the libatlas.a, nm shows that ATL_buildinfo is present.

What could be the problem?

Comment: When you try that `gcc ...` line, what is the error you get, exactly?

Comment: move the main.c like "$gcc main.c -I..-L...". this should do it.

Comment: it seems its a static library. you can get the whole fuss away if you supply the library directly in cli. like $gcc main.c -I.... $dir/libatlas.a

Comment: @aftnix - Nice catch. If you were able to reproduce the problem, and then fix it with this - it should be an answer. Also check out `-static`.

Comment: As to the other bit, i.e. moving `main.c` earlier in the argument list, I think that won't work. If main references a library, the corresponding `-l` needs to appear before `main.c` in the list.

Comment: @ArjunShankar I'm getting (.text + 0x25): Undefined reference to ATL_buildinfo. Right now I'm rebuilding ATLAS to see if that works, when it's done I will check the -static

Comment: @aftnix I believe GCC found the library, otherwise it would have failed with "library not found"

Comment: @ArjunShankar from my experience, (Never bothered to understand why, but i should have researched it), sometimes it does work that way. Like i have libnetfilter_queue app in my box which compiles like this: gcc main.c other.c -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue. if i move -l flags before main.c it shows "linker error". I faced same kind of things in numerous occasion. may because of the way gnu linker works, if you have a object code which references a symbol, you have to put the object code which contains the symbol after the object code of referring object.

Comment: @Caian errors like (.text + 0x25) is a linker error. which means it can't resolve a symbol reference. The error occurred in "linking" stage rather than compiling stage. another thing is, its trying to link to shared library. If that is what you want(you have the shared library available with .so extension) then its ok. otherwise make sure it links with static library.

Comment: @aftnix Who would tell... it actually did work changing main.c to the beginning! Please do a formal response so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: This is strange. I would love to see an explanation! @aftnix, what say find out and let us know for good this time? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving the main.c before linker flags may solve it.

```
$gcc main.c -I..-L...".
```

This should solve the problem.

This works because of the way "linking order" is imposed by gnu linker.

The traditional behavior of linkers is to search for external functions from left to right in the libraries specified on the command line. This means that a library containing the definition of a function should appear after any source files or object files which use it. This includes libraries specified with the short-cut -l option, as shown in the following command.

```
$ gcc -Wall calc.c -lm -o calc   (correct order)
```

This link explains this behaviour:

http://chara.epfl.ch/~fsalvi/docs/gcc/www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html